# Cannot access files on FTP server from Azure Data Factory

Tags: ftp, azure-data-factory

I currently have access to a third party's FTP server which, upon login, automatically redirects me to a directory that does not contain the files I am trying to download.

ftp://ftp.fakehost.com -> ftp://ftp.fakehost.com/uselessDir

My files are in ftp://ftp.fakehost/usefulDir.

This ftp server does not support directory traversal so I cannot get to usefulDir by simply modifying my url. FileZilla works since I can execute specific ftp commands to get to the directory I want.

Can a Data Factory FTP service or dataset be customized to work around this problem since Data Factory cannot access the usefulDir directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I doesn't understand your question correctly. Have you tried create a dataset and manually put the usefulDir in folderPath property directly, instead of using the Authoring UI to navigate to that folder (which is not possible based on your description.)

Comment: I can't upvote you since I don't have the rep but this comment is here to say that you provided me with the answer.
I believe the authoring UI is a bit confusing when it asks to specify a folder and file path to the data you are trying to copy since it adds input boxes separated by '/' but these '/' are not included in the final json so essentially my paths were relative and not absolute.